# Pass value to referenced subroutine in perl

Tags: perl, subroutine

I have few referenced subroutine and I need to pass the value to the referenced subroutine.
Is there any way to do it.

```
   #Sample Code
   sub CreateHtmlBox {
     my ($box_type,$hash_ref) = @_;
     my %subCall = (
        'singlebox'   =>  \&CreateSingleBox   ,
        'multiplebox' =>  \&CreateMultipleBox
              );

     my $htmlCode = $subCall->($box_html);
   }

   sub CreateSingleBox {
    my ($box_type) =@_;
    #...................
    return $htmlCode;
   }
```

I want to call referenced subroutine and pass the reference of hash to it.

```
   CreateSingleBox($hash_ref)
```

Comment: it's not clear what value you need to pass to the subroutine you're calling. anyway, a level is missing in your example: `$subCall->($box_html)` should be (assuming you want to call `CreateSingleBox`): `$subcCall{singlebox}->( $box_html )`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to access an specific element in the hash before you can call it as a coderef. I.e.

```
# WRONG! Variable $subCall does not exist.
my $htmlCode = $subCall->($box_html);
```

should really be

```
my $htmlCode = $subCall{box_type}($box_html);
```

The resulting code would look like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub CreateHtmlBox {
    my ($box_type, $hash_ref) = @_;
    my %subCall = (
        singlebox   => \&CreateSingleBox,
        multiplebox => \&CreateMultipleBox,
    );
    return $subCall{$box_type}($hash_ref);
}

sub CreateSingleBox {
    my ($box_type) = @_;
    my $htmlCode= "<p>" . $box_type->{a} . "</p>";
    return $htmlCode;
}

print CreateHtmlBox("singlebox",{a => 1})
```